# Is the SignalR project stale?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm looking to create a new asp.net mvc app with some realtime functionality. I looked into SignalR on GitHub and there are several open issues and it appears to have low activity on the project. Is SignalR an active project and good choice to use still?

Comment: Interesting.  In the short, yes, it is still an active project as far as we are all aware.  It appears based on the NuGet page (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR), that releases were about every 2-3 months until this year (2015).  I wonder if the .NET 5.0 beta framework is what they have been focusing on?  Thanks for your question btw, I just spent seemingly 10 minutes going through GitHub branches for that project :)

Comment: FWIW - https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap (towards the bottom of the page)

Comment: The guy who created SignalR is not one of the ASP.NET architects, so the team focused on creating ASP.NET5. Next year they will release SignalR 3.